# Ncqrs: How to store events as part of test set-up

Tags: tdd, ncqrs

How do I store events as part of setting up my tests?

Currently I'm initializing application state by sending commands like this:

```
Given some commands were sent
When sending another command
Then some events should have been published
```

I'm using `ICommandService.Execute()` to send the Commands in the `Given` and `When` parts.

Since commands can be rejected by the domain, I wouldn't want to rely on them. I'd rather set up my application state by simulating events like this:

```
Given _some events_ occurred
When sending a command
Then some events should have been published
```

How do I push the events from `Given` into the event store so that they can be replayed during handling the "When" part?

Thanks

Dennis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have been given the answer on the mailing list and will add this for further reference:

I was using an old version of Ncqrs. The current version exposes `Ncqrs.Eventing.Storage.IEventStore.Store()` which takes an event stream and can be uses during test set-up just as needed.